# Optional updates won't download

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v2004

When I checked for updates on Windows 10, version 2004, Windows Updated indicated that there were optional updates available. I selected the update and clicked "Download and Install." Windows checked for updates again and displayed the same results without installing the update. I repeated this a few times to no avail. Please help.

Update: Screenshot provided.[image: WinUpdate]

Error code 0x8024004C.

Comment: Try Windows Update Repair. Sometimes it actually does help.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Windows Update.  I suspect I know what’s going on.  Please also provide the last cumulative update you have installed

Comment: @Ramhound The last cumulative update was [KB4570721](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4570721/kb4570721-cumulative-update-for-net-framework).

Comment: @DCcatMarvelCatNoMore - Windows cumlative update not .NET Framework.

Comment: I've had this problem in the past as well. I simply waited until the next update, which fixed it automatically ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score -2):

I ran sfc/scannow and retried the update. That fixed it. Source: [800error](https://www.800error.com/error-code-0x8024004C-Windows-error-Update-System-Firmware)